# Why using keystore value in Elasticsearch helm chart results in this error?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes-helm, minio

I was trying to use the Elasticsearch helm chart here (https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/elastic/elasticsearch)

I created a secret called s3-creds-pass, with my username and pass

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  s3.client.default.access_key: dXNlcg==
  s3.client.default.secret_key: cGFzc3dvcmQ=
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: s3-creds-pass
  namespace: elastic
```

Then I installed the repo and only changed those values:

```
keystore:
  - secretName: s3-creds-pass

replicas: 1
minimumMasterNodes: 1


service:
  enabled: true
  type: NodePort
  nodePort: "30920"
```

All the time I get this error

```
k -n elastic logs elasticsearch-master-0  -f
Defaulted container "elasticsearch" out of: elasticsearch, configure-sysctl (init), keystore (init)
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.keystore.tmp -> /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.keystore: Device or resource busy
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:100)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.move(UnixCopyFile.java:420)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.move(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:266)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1430)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.KeyStoreWrapper.save(KeyStoreWrapper.java:498)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.KeyStoreWrapper.save(KeyStoreWrapper.java:412)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.keystore.AddStringKeyStoreCommand.executeCommand(AddStringKeyStoreCommand.java:102)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.keystore.BaseKeyStoreCommand.execute(BaseKeyStoreCommand.java:64)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:54)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:85)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.MultiCommand.execute(MultiCommand.java:94)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:85)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:50)
        at org.elasticsearch.launcher.CliToolLauncher.main(CliToolLauncher.java:64)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you tried this?
https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/issues/90#issuecomment-498267140

Comment: I tried it, yes and it didn't work!